# AngularJS não está funcionando

Tags: angularjs

por que as vezes, quando chamamos o angular, ele não funciona?
Vejam meu HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='weset'>
<head>
<title>WESET</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row login">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">{{3+4}}
            <form name="formLogin">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" ng-mmodel="usuario.email">
                <label>Senha</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha" ng-mmodel="usuario.senha">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="formLogin.$invalid" ng-click="logar(usuario)">Logar</a>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Aquele {{3+4}} deveria aparecer como 7, quando rodo a página, mas isso não acontece, por isso sei que o angular não está funcionando.

Comment: O que mais eu deveria fazer @jbueno?
Sempre pego a CDN e inicio com <html ng-app="nomeApp" e funciona!

Comment: De que módulos vc etá falando @MuriloGambôa? o app.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Toda e qualquer aplicação Angular, precisa da diretiva `ng-app` para funcionar, nela você referencia o `module` criado por você pra representar a aplicação.

Já que o AngularJS não define um método para o *start* da aplicação. É a criação do módulo que define como sua aplicação vai ser inicializada, quais as dependências dela, etc.

Também não vejo nenhum controller no exemplo que foi dado.

Aqui um exemplo do seu código funcional.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('mainController', mainControllerFn);

function mainControllerFn(){

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="row login" ng-controller="mainController">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">{{3+4}}
      <form name="formLogin">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" ng-mmodel="usuario.email">
          <label>Senha</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha" ng-mmodel="usuario.senha">
          <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="formLogin.$invalid" ng-click="logar(usuario)">Logar</a>
      </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem um `ng-app` na tag html dele. Seria isso?

Comment: Eu vi, mas não é isso o problema. A diretiva **`ng-app`** precisa estar referenciando um módulo válido.

Comment: Pior, eu esqueci que tinha que criar o módulo.
valeu @jbueno